# Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY not working

Tags: java, loops, audio, wav

please help me figure out why my wav file is not looping and how do I call this class on my mousepressed event on a different class? Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;

public class Test2 {
    {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {

          Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
          AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioPlayer.class.getResourceAsStream("ATS.wav"));         
          clip.open(inputStream);
          clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
      }
    }).start();  
  }     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to loop it, you must start it.

```
clip.start();
```

To call it from another location, use `new Test2();`.

Comment: Why is it not working? I have this on another class. And it doesn't loop. it just starts. MouseAdapter m3 = new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0){
   super.mousePressed(arg0);
   if(music.contains(arg0.getX(), arg0.getY())){
   new Test2();
   
   }
   
  }
 };

Comment: @rgstrdnny I'm not sure; you may have to check the documentation. This is the most information that I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Thread maybe something in the try like:

```
Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength()/1000);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.